# Make Xbox music remember that I want to shuffle music

Tags: windows-8, xbox-music

I don't know if this is intentional or a problem of my computer, but Xbox Music doesn't remember that I want to have music shuffled.

For example when I go in my library and select an album, it's played in the track order, not shuffled.

Comment: Is there any other situation in which the shuffle setting is ignored? Playing a specific album could be set to ignore that preference.

Comment: Playing an album in streaming. Smart dj (obviously) or "play all" will shuffle